# How to prevent change uploaded image type JPG to JPEG

Tags: php, image, types

This script automatically change uploaded image type `JPG` to `JPEG`

How to prevent? I do not want to change image type.

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) && ($_FILES["myfile"]["size"] <= 8192 * 1 * 8192)) {
   $enabled = array(
       IMAGETYPE_PNG,
       IMAGETYPE_JPEG
   );
   list($width, $height, $extension) = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
   if (in_array($extension, $enabled)) {
       $ext     = image_type_to_extension($extension, true);
       $newname = $username . $id . '-' . time() . $ext;
       $imglink = $upload_folder . '/' . $newname;
       if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], "$upload_folder/" . $newname))

       $result     = 1;
```

Comment: How do you see that the image type was changed?

Comment: What happens if you echo $ext? And echo $extension too.

Comment: If I upload image with type JPG result I receive with type JPEG: $username . $id . '-' . time() . JPEG

Comment: I`m sorry, I do not understant how to "echo $ext? And echo $extension too."?

Comment: What is the value of your variables $ext and $extension. Usually that can be found out using one of the following methods: echo, var_dump, print_r or var_export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the original extension from the file data not `image_type_to_extension`

replace this line

```
$ext     = image_type_to_extension($extension, true);
```

with this

```
$ext = "." . strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['myfile']["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

EDIT: to allow `JPG` extension you have to do your own check after you have confirmed the image is a real image file with `getimagesize()`.

```
$allowedExtensions = ['jpg','png','jpeg'];
if(in_array($ext, $allowedExtensions)){
    //it's an allowed extension 
}
```

Comment: My problem solved. Thank you. How I receive image with type JPG.

Comment: Add the extensions you want to allow in your `$enabled` array .